# Python Discord Bot adding number and colon at start of every line in text file

Tags: python, discord.py

I've inserted the code from my discord bot, and the program successfully takes the content of a discord message and inserts it into the two text files I created. What I can't figure out is, when I type the following into the discord channel: "Hi world" the text files that I am writing to end up with the following message: "10:Hi world". What is causing this?

```
import discord

Templetext = 'currentmsg.txt'
Logfile = 'templelog.txt'
newline = ord('\n')

client = discord.Client()

print('I am on')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('The Gods are listening')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    with open(Templetext, "w") as file1:
        file1.write(f" {message.content}")
    with open(Logfile, "a") as file2:
        file2.write(f" {message.content}, {newline}")
client.run('XYZ')
```

Comment: Why are you saving `newline` as `ord("\n")` not just `"\n"`? The result of `ord("\n")` is `10`, so that might have something to do with it, although I'm not sure where the colon is coming from. Try printing out the content of the message and seeing whether or not it is what you expect.

Comment: so I had tried just "\n" in the line file2.write(f" {message.content}, \n") and getting an error. I will take that out and try again to use the "\n"

Answer (score 1):

The usage of `ord` is unnecessary. Try this:

```
with open(Logfile, "a") as file2:
        file2.write(message.content + "\n")
```